# Transform forms from Symfony2 to Symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to transform a form like this to comply with Symfony3 code :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AjoutQC(array('idcolle' => $idColle,'idqc' => $question->getId())),
                              $question,
                              array('action' => $this->generateUrl('paces_colle_qc_update',
                                                                    array(
                                                                          'id'  => $question->getId(),
                                                                          'idColle'  => $idColle,
                                                                          'idTuteur' => $idTuteur)
                                                                    ),
                                    'method'   => 'PUT',
                              ));

    $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Sauvegarder'));
```

Symfony3 asks for something like :

```
AjoutQC::class
```

instead of :

```
new AjoutQC...
```

I didn't find anything about it after some research.

Comment: There are some tips at https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade including tools [Symfony Upgrade Fixer](https://github.com/umpirsky/Symfony-Upgrade-Fixer) and [deprecation detector](https://github.com/sensiolabs-de/deprecation-detector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony 3 you need to use [FQCN](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form) (fully-qualified class name) instead of an instance of the form (or a string reference to a service).

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    AjoutQC::class,
    $question,
    array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl(
            'paces_colle_qc_update', 
            array(
                'id'       => $question->getId(),
                'idColle'  => $idColle,
                'idTuteur' => $idTuteur
            )
        ),
        'method'  => 'PUT',
        'idColle' => $idColle,
        'idQc'    => $question->getId()
    )
)
```

In your `AjoutQC` class you need to go to your `configureOptions` method and add the `idcolle` and `idqc` options:

```
class AjoutQC extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array('idColle','idQc'));
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Your\Entity\Path',
                'idColle'    => null,
                'idQc'       => null
            )
        );
    }        
}
```

Comment: This worked for all my forms but one which is throwing me this error : Warning: Illegal string offset.
`public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    { $builder
                ->add('nom'              , TextType::class  , array('disabled' => $this->options['modificationInterdite']))

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setRequired(array('modificationInterdite'));
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'modificationInterdite'                => false
        ));
    }`

Comment: You should open up a new question for this with your full code. I believe you've either missed a field in the `FormType` or if you have embedded sub `FormType`s, you might have to go through them as well.

Answer (score 3):

Check these upgrade [notes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form) for forms.

It says:

> Passing type instances to Form::add(), FormBuilder::add() and the FormFactory::create*() methods is not supported anymore. Pass the fully-qualified class name of the type instead.

**Before:**

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyType());
```

**After:**

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyType::class);
```

You can use [OptionsResolver](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolverInterface.html) and pass your data `array('idcolle' => $idColle,'idqc' => $question->getId())` that you are currently passing to your form type as a third argument to `createForm` method:

```
$form = $this->createForm(AjoutQC::class, $question, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('paces_colle_qc_update', array(
        'id' => $question->getId(),
        'idColle' => $idColle,
        'idTuteur' => $idTuteur,
     )),
     'method' => 'PUT',
     'idcolle' => $idColle,
     'idqc' => $question->getId(),
));
```

Then in your `AjoutQC` type you need to do something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

// ..    

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->idcolle = $options['idcolle'];
    $this->idqc = $options['idqc'];

    $builder
        ->add(...)
        // ..
    ;
}

// ..

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array('idcolle', 'idqc'));
}
```

This will set `idcolle`, `idqc` options as required, that must be passed to your form type (`AjoutQC`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wondering about the `::class` notation, you can find information about that here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

`::class` requires php >= 5.5

If you are using <5.5 you can just simply use the FQCN e.g. `MyLong\Namespace\Fully\Qualified\ClassNameType`